# Query Latest 7 days in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have a data set in this format:

```
Col1                    Col2    Col3
26/04/19 10:10:00   0.03    0.037
26/04/19 16:30:00   0.03    0.037
26/04/19 22:01:00   0.03    0.037
27/04/19 04:15:00   0.03    0.037
27/04/19 10:15:00   0.03    0.037
04/05/19 01:15:00   0.03    0.037
04/05/19 06:05:00   0.03    0.037
04/05/19 11:12:00   0.03    0.037
04/05/19 16:21:00   0.00    0.037
04/05/19 22:27:00   0.03    0.037
05/05/19 04:35:00   0.03    0.037
05/05/19 10:31:00   0.03    0.037
05/05/19 16:13:00   0.03    0.037
05/05/19 22:05:00   0.03    0.037
06/05/19 04:10:00   0.00    0.037
```

And I wish to query the latest 7 days data. In this case will be the latest 7 days data from 06/05/19 04:10:00. which is until 31/4/19 04:10:00. So I wish to query all data from 31/4/19 04:10:00 to 06/05/19 04:10:00.

Expected Outcome:

```
Col1                    Col2    Col3
04/05/19 01:15:00   0.03    0.037
04/05/19 06:05:00   0.03    0.037
04/05/19 11:12:00   0.03    0.037
04/05/19 16:21:00   0.00    0.037
04/05/19 22:27:00   0.03    0.037
05/05/19 04:35:00   0.03    0.037
05/05/19 10:31:00   0.03    0.037
05/05/19 16:13:00   0.03    0.037
05/05/19 22:05:00   0.03    0.037
06/05/19 04:10:00   0.00    0.037
```

The catch is this google sheet is not static. It's dynamic and keeps getting updated. The dates are always in order but can have more than 1 entry per date.

Formulas I have tried so far:

```
=SORT(QUERY(A14:C,"order by A desc limit 7"),1,1)
```

and

```
=QUERY(A14:C,"Select * where A >= date '"&TEXT(INDEX(SORT(A14:C,1,false),MATCH(true,ISNUMBER(INDEX(SORT(A14:C,1,false),,2)),0),1)-6,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' limit 7")
```

The 1st formula gives me a blanket last 7 dates in my range. The 2nd formula is specific for date and is only feasible when there are no date duplications. Hence both the formulas don't fit my needs

[Google Sheet Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15Oc92wyBZgwgsUC1Ckexrla8KkVn86mlT3ocP2GG0c4/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

See if this works

```
=sort(query(A14:C, "Where A is not null order by A desc limit 7"), 1, 1)
```

Alternatively, you can also try

```
=offset(A1, counta(A:A)-7, 0, 7, 3)
```

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet so I can see why it doesn't work?

Comment: i have added the link of the google sheet to my question. Thank you very much

Comment: Part of your dates (marked in blue) is not correctly formatted and are not recognized as numbers/dates. Updated my answer with an alternative approach.

Comment: But this only returns me the last 7 data. Not the last 7 days worth of data which is from date 31/4/19  to 06/05/19.

Comment: Then query will probably be your best bet. I suggest to try the formula posted by player0 and see if that works for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY({A:C}, "where Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),   "yyyy-MM-dd")&"' 
                 and Col1 >  date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-7, "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A2:C, DATE(20&MID(A2:A, 7, 2), MID(A2:A, 4, 2), LEFT(A2:A, 2))},
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3
  where Col4 <= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),   "yyyy-MM-dd")&"' 
    and Col4 >  date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-7, "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'", 0))
```

[image: 0]